# Sort function failing for larger arrays

Tags: c, sorting

I'm writing a program to implement *Prim's Algorithm* for minimum spanning trees for a short project for a course. The first step is to sort the edges according to weight; the code I have for this works sometimes, but not always.

Here is the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < graph.edges; ++i) 
{
    least_remain_edge = i;

    for(int k=i+1; k<graph.edges; ++k)
    {
        if(graph.edge[k][3]<graph.edge[least_remain_edge][3])
        {
            least_remain_edge = k;
        }
    }

    if(least_remain_edge != i)
    {
        swap_temp = graph.edge[i][0];
        graph.edge[i][0] = graph.edge[least_remain_edge][0];
        graph.edge[least_remain_edge][0] = swap_temp;
    }
}
```

`graph.edge[i][3]` is the `weight` of the `i`th edge, and `[i][0]` is the edges reference/name. It's something like a bubble sort, where it finds the smallest in the remainder of the list, and puts it in the `i`th place. I can't see why this isn't always working!

Comment: What doesn't work? Does it sort incorrectly, or does it throw an error?

Comment: It doesnt sort properly. Like, really badly in fact. it took [3,4,1,3] and gave back [1,3,4,3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're moving around elements, you're only moving their name/reference around, and not the weights and whatever else you're storing. So, maybe do something like

```
for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
    swap_temp = graph.edge[i][k];
    graph.edge[i][k] = graph.edge[least_remain_edge][k];
    graph.edge[least_remain_edge][k] = swap_temp;
}
```

Comment: I added this in.. it didn't remedy the issue :/. I tried a longer list of edges, and it took [1,3,5,4,2,2,4,3,5] and gave back [1,2,3,5,4,2,3,5,4]!

Comment: @FireGarden Well, then you're going to have to show more code. I implemented this [here](http://ideone.com/4TVfTZ) and it runs just fine. So there's something else going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for trying - I avoided the problem altogether by using a not-so-nice sorting function which was more brutal, but it worked.